# shell command line to run a script N times

Tags: shell

I'm trying to run a curl command for the following numbers but it doesn't apply

```
for i in {2,51,52,53,54}; do curl -v -X PUT http://localhost:8198/v3/progress/i/?status=Open; done
```

anything going wrong ?

Comment: You probably want to use `$i` (note the dollar-sign) inside the loop, not just `i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you can use variables with `$`. So `i` should be `$i`

This should make it work:

`for i in {2,51,52,53,54}; do curl -v -X PUT http://localhost:8198/v3/progress/$i/?status=Open; done`

Comment: how can I provide this list as argument ?

Comment: You can split a string on comma and loop over that array. Something like this: http://rextester.com/AUSQJF58875